# Python precision of float is lost while converting to string

Tags: python, scapy

I am using Scapy's `sniff` function for reading packets from a pcap file.

```
pkt=sniff(offline="a.pcap",count=1)[0]
```

In IDLE with `pkt.time`, I am able to get the time-stamp of the packet i.e. `1431063004.998014`. But when I tried to convert the time-stamp to a string with `str(pkt.time)` or instead of `pkt.time` I give `print pkt.time`, I get only `1431063005.0`.

Is it possible to get the exact time-stamp value as a string??

**Note:**
I looked in to `decimal` module. But that requires the precision number. That won't help without knowing the number of digits, I guess.

Comment: Try `pkt.time.__repr__()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`repr` is another method like `str` which converts the whole float with precision. No need to import `decimal` or anything. Use it just like you use `str` and it returns a `str` object only.

```
>>> x = repr(pkt.time)
>>> type(x)
>>> <type 'str'>
```

Comment: @RatDon If I were you, I'd mention in my answer the `%r` format code, as in `print "%r"%pkt.time`.  I'd bet that `"{...}".format()` also has a corresponding format code...

Comment: @gboffi I tried to accept the answer but there was time constraint by SO. and then i got busy in my work...and thank you...

Comment: @gboffi Sorry. I'm not a expert. I don't know that `%r` format. I've used `repr` before for somewhat the same purpose, so mentioned that only. Thanks for informing something new. You can edit the answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
"{:.6f}".format(pkt.time)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  "{:.6f}".format(pkt.time)
```

Comment: @user3238855 I see my answer inspired you :-)

Comment: @MartinBeseda: Look at the timestamps. Who inspired whom?

Comment: @user3238855 But you´ve changed your answer to be the completely same as mine 6 minutes after me :-) It doesn´t matter, I just consider it funny :-)